# Ant Build ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java workspace

Tags: java, build, ant, ibm-rad, antbuilder

I am trying to build a Web Application with Ant build script. Application has many modules and after compiling couple of projects build fails with following error logs:

[javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.4.2). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
**[javac] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25459**

It's an Java 4 application. Have tried building it with *Ant version 1.7 and 1.8* but both fails with same error.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
[javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.4.2). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
[javac] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25459
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.ClassReader.readPool(ClassReader.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.ClassReader.readName(ClassReader.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.ClassReader.readClassAttrs(ClassReader.java:795)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.ClassReader.readClassFile(ClassReader.java:963)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:1121)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:1076)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.ClassReader.loadClass(ClassReader.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Resolve.loadClass(Resolve.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Resolve.findIdentInPackage(Resolve.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Attr.selectSym(Attr.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.tree.Tree$Select.accept(Tree.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Enter$MemberEnter.visitImport(Enter.java:780)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.tree.Tree$Import.accept(Tree.java:424)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Enter$MemberEnter.memberEnter(Enter.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Enter$MemberEnter.memberEnter(Enter.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Enter$MemberEnter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:763)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.tree.Tree$TopLevel.accept(Tree.java:407)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Enter$MemberEnter.memberEnter(Enter.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Enter$CompleteEnter.complete(Enter.java:865)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java(Compiled Code))
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:708)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:618)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:599)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:348)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.v8.Main.compile(Main.java:586)
[javac] at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:67)
[javac] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[javac] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:85)
[javac] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:58)
[javac] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[javac] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1134)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[javac] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
[javac] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[javac] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[javac] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[javac] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:85)
[javac] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:58)
[javac] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[javac] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[javac] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[javac] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:85)
[javac] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:58)
[javac] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[javac] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[javac] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
[javac] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[javac] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[javac] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
```

Comment: Please take a minute to look at your post from the point of view of another person reading it.  What is your question?  Did you follow the link and try to find out if this is a reported bug?  Consider the likelihood someone can advise you from one stack trace with very little information about the context.  You'll probably have to narrow this down to give us a chance of helping.  Maybe try a "divide and conquer" approach: what's the smallest amount of build that generates the error?

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have tried to provide the narrowed view of the problem and it is not a reported bug. Sometime, the stack trace are very useful and if someone has faced similar issue would guess it immediately. Thanks for you suggestion though and will follow your advice. After struggling for 2 days I have finally found the solution to it and will post it for others reference.

Comment: Glad you found it - looks like a tricky one to spot!

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for two days finally issue was found. This was caused by **duplicate .class** files in the JAR. This is very strange as I have seen ant  tasks copies the duplicate .class file (with warning in verbose mode -v) while packaging JARs. Here is the snippet from the build script file which was the culprit:

```
<jar destfile="${dir_dest}" manifest="${dir_src}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
    <fileset dir="${dir_dest}" />   
    <fileset dir="${dir_src}" excludes="**/*.java"/> 
</jar>
```

Script ran successfully after I deleted:

```
<fileset dir="${dir_dest}" />
```

Following link helped me to figure out the issue:
http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/corrupt-jar-files-and-javac-td1359404.html

Other links where identical (or similar) issue is reported but no answers:
https://coderanch.com/t/68624/application-servers/EJB-Complie-failure

https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/i-need-to-develop-a-jm-plugin-but-compile-file-is-error/73578/6